# Put and get intents in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent

I'm kinda new in Android and really want to learn it but got stuck on one tutorial. This tutorial is about downloading and showing image in `gridview` with some text. So far I get the images, text and everything. The problem occur when I want to open the item from that gridview and show big image and text. I am able to show the image but I can't figured out how exactly to pass the text via intent.
This is Activity 1

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
public String resultServer = "";
public String text;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Download JSON File   
    new DownloadJSONFileAsync().execute();

}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

// Show All Content
public void ShowAllContent()
{
    // gridView1
    final GridView gridV = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 
    gridV.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Restaurants.this,MyArrList));

    // OnClick
    gridV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
            String Position = String.valueOf(position);

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(Main.this,MainTwo.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position);
            newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer);
            newActivity.putExtra("text", resultServer);
            startActivity(newActivity);

        }
    });
}
```

I've added this line into `Intent newActivity` -> `newActivity.putExtra("text", resultServer);`
and this is Activity 2 -

```
public class MainTwo extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_JSON_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public int curPosition  = 0;
public String resultServer;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> MyArrList;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_two);


    Intent intent= getIntent();
    curPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Position")); 
    resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("resultServer")); 
    resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

    try {
        MyArrList = ConvertJSONtoArrayList(resultServer);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("ArrayList Size",String.valueOf(MyArrList.size()));

    // Show Image Full
    new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();

    // Button Home
    final Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
    // Perform action on click
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainTwo.this, Main.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });

}

// Show Image Full
public void ShowImageFull(String imageName, Bitmap imgFull)
{

     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

     try
     {
        image.setImageBitmap(imgFull);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // When Error
        image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
     }

     // Show Toast
    Toast.makeText(MainTwo.this,imageName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> ConvertJSONtoArrayList(String json) throws JSONException
{

    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("ImageID", (String)c.getString("id"));
        map.put("ImageName", (String)c.getString("name"));
        map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("image"));
        map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("rest_img_big"));
        map.put("text", (String)c.getString("text"));

        arr.add(map);
    }

    return arr;

}
```

Here I add in `for` block -> map.put("text", (String)c.getString("text"));`

and in get intent part `resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("text"));`
This is `main_two.xml` And I see `Home` button, blank space where should be `text` and the big image.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnHome"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Home" />

</TableRow>

<View
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout> 
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1">   

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fullimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#CCCCCC" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

If you need more source I will post it.
May be is really lame question but I can't figured it alone. Please help.
Update

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "URL to download data";

        JSONArray data;
        try {
            resultServer = getJSONUrl(url);
            data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("id", (String)c.getString("id"));
                map.put("name", (String)c.getString("name"));
                map.put("text", (String)c.getString("text"));

                // Thumbnail Get ImageBitmap To Bitmap
                map.put("ImagePathThum", (String)c.getString("image"));
                map.put("ImageThumBitmap", (Bitmap)loadBitmap(c.getString("image")));

                // Full (for View Full)
                map.put("ImagePathFull", (String)c.getString("rest_img_big"));

                MyArrList.add(map);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: how you initialize resultServer ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana, I have updated my question. Did you mean this?

Comment: why you pass two time resultServer one as resultServer and another as text key ?

Comment: As per my understanding when you click grid item you wan to show clicked some data in MainTwo is it ?

Comment: Yes, and as I said is working. But I want to pass also text because now is showing only the image in second activity

Comment: So you need only image and text only in second activity ?

Comment: As I understand it in SecondActivity should show me the text because I have this `resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("resultServer")); `. Isn't this grab everything?

Comment: Yes, and currently is only image. Need also text

Comment: So there is no need to pass whole json array string only get image and text from list hashmap

Comment: How exactly to take text? and assigned to `TextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass only particular item full image path and text instead of json array string :

How to pass from First Activity :

```
gridV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
     Intent newActivity = new Intent(Main.this,MainTwo.class);
     newActivity.putExtra("image", MyArrList.get(position).get("imagePathFull").toString());
     newActivity.putExtra("text", MyArrList.get(position).get("text").toString());
     startActivity(newActivity);
   }
});
```

How to get on Second Activity :

```
 String fullImagePath;
 String text;

 fullImagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePathFull");
 text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
```

Comment: Just tried but is still empty. Do I need to assign `text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");` to TextView?

Comment: I've put this `TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);` but still

Comment: i try to get text and full image from  MyArrList using grid click item position please try check value in grid item click.

Comment: Still I don't get the text in second activity. Only in first.

Comment: I need also position of the grid item. So I can't delete `curPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Position")); `

Comment: It doesn't work at all with this. The app crash every time because of `MyArrList` errors.

Comment: Actually you gave me starting point and I figured it out. Thank's!